# Launch app using 3D touch from cold AND debug through Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, 3dtouch

I am trying to debug an issue with the 3D touch implementation in my iOS app. The issue is only present when the app is not already running in the background (IE the app has been force closed previously, either by they system or user).

The issue is, when I force close the app after launching it through Xcode, then use a 3D touch action to open it, it's not running through the debugger and therefore I can't debug the issue.

I have tried going to `Debug>Attach to Process` but by the time I have done so, the code in question has already run.

TL;DR, is there a way to launch an app through Xcode, as if one of the 3D touch actions had done so?

Many Thanks,

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33090860/2386527 The solution is quite simple.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, that's super helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launching with UIApplicationShortcutItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801182/launching-with-uiapplicationshortcutitem)

Comment: I have voted to close as is effectively a duplicate, please do so as well.